# Not able to find out the id of the button for which a jquery function was called?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-wizard

I have two buttons in my Twitter Bootstrap wizard :-

```
<div class="form-actions">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <ul class="pager wizard no-margin">
                <!--<li class="previous first disabled">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-lg btn-default"> First </a>
                </li>-->
                <li class="previous disabled">
                        <a id="prev" href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-lg btn-default"> Previous </a>
                </li>
                <!--<li class="next last">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"> Last </a>
                </li>-->
                <li class="next" id="skip">
                        <a id="skip" href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-lg txt-color-darken"> Skip </a>
                </li>
                <li class="next" id="next">
                        <a id="next" href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-lg txt-color-darken"> Next </a>
                </li>
                 <li class="next finish" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:;">Finish</a></li>
                 <input type='button' class='btn button-last btn-default' style="display:none;" name='last' value='Skip GG setup' />
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, the Bootstrap wizard has a function called `onNext`. Now in this function I am trying to find out which button the user clicked on to trigger this event. I tried something as shown in the code below but it doesn't really work.

```
$('#bootstrap-wizard-1').bootstrapWizard({
    'tabClass': 'form-wizard',
    'onNext': function (tab, navigation, index) {
        $("li.next").click(function() {
            var id = "";
            id = this.id; // or alert($(this).attr('id'));
            alert(id);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you don't need to add a `click` handler in the `onNext` function.

Comment: What @Steve said. You're *setting* the click handler in the `onNext` callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your need to remove the click handler function.
You can get the index of the clicked tab.
Your HTML is not accurate or not complete. [Check the documentation](https://github.com/VinceG/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/blob/master/examples/basic-formvalidation.html).

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VD83m/1/) example.

UPDATE:
This way you get the ID. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardonunez/qW42J/)

```
$('#bootstrap-wizard-1').bootstrapWizard({
    'tabClass': 'form-wizard',
    'onNext': function (tab, navigation, index) {
        //
    }
});

$("li.next").click(function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.id);   // get the id
});
```

Comment: But how can he get the element which triggered the event from inside the `onNext` callback?

Comment: I don`t want the index of the tab. I want the ID of the button which was clicked for which the onNext function was called i.e. either the Next or the SKip button

Comment: Can you explain it too Ricardo. Thanks.

Comment: You can see all the properties of the DOM object by doing console.log(event). Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target

Answer (score 0):

I can't get to the Wizard docs right now, but I think this is what you'd need to do:

```
'onNext': function (tab, navigation, index) {
    var id = $(tab).attr('id');
    alert(id);
}
```

If that doesn't work, you can probably use the index to get it:

```
'onNext': function (tab, navigation, index) {
    var id = $('.wizard > li').eq(index).attr('id');
    alert(id);
}
```

Should probably put an ID on the `ul` to avoid ambiguity with the selector.